# Is there any other way without array modifier?

Tags: modeling

I am looking for a way to model circular objects without array modifier. Something like this for example:

[image]

Edit: as you can see the dimensions tab has numbers. I think that is what's messing the mesh around. Have I modelled my basic part incorrectly ? Is there a way to reset the dimensions of an object?  [image]

Comment: Why do you wanna avoid array modifier if it only improve your workflow and save you time?

Comment: because in my case I  have dimensions not equal to zero so I am getting distortions. This is with the transformation and rotation applied, but i have altered dimensions that I cannot clear

Comment: dId not understand your issue with "not equal to zero" are you saying that your model has a distortion and the "Wheel" is not a perfect circle?

Comment: Remodelled my mesh and did everything from the beginning. It worked. Would be helpful to know how to reset the dimmensions though.

Comment: Your scale is correct ... they are all 1.0, this means that you have not altered your dimension in any way after you created the object. What do you mean you cannot clear the dimension? The dimension is an imaginary bounding 3-dimensional box around your model. If you change the value in the dimension ... you will notice that scale factor also changes depending on the amount you stretch your model in respective axis.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I misunderstood the workings of the array modifier. It is clear to me now. This should be deleted. Thanks for the replies hawkenfox. Got some information from your last post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe you can use both X and Y symmetry in the mirror modifier.**

Like so..
[image]

[image]

It does depend on the complexity of your subject. In many cases Array will give you more control than the mirror modifier but for less complex objects this may be helpful.